# How to re-enable wlan0 after backports disabled it

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, html

I have a PC with Ubuntu 14.10 and I tried to install backports following [the instructions here](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath10k/backports) (except for cooked monitor interface, compiling my own, and I couldn't check if I had ath10k firmware, I was offline at the time [saved it as a html file]). I checked "iwconfig" and all I got was "eth0" and "lo". I tried "iwconfig wlan0" and it said "no such device". How do I fix this?

Comment: To answer this, please provide the output of *lspci -vnn | grep -i net*

Comment: All I got was "02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8187SE Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8199] (rev 22)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)" Then I typed in iwconfig and wlan0 wasn't even there.